# Firebase storage not working Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'am trying to update a photo on Firebase Storage.

Rules for Storage are public and all libraries are up to date.

For bucket I'm using the one from my firebase console.

> Fatal Exception:
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied bucketname is not
>   available to this project.  at
>   com.moose.android.AddPostActivity.onClick(AddPostActivity.java:163)

```
                                Bitmap bitmap = imageBitmap;
                                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
                                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                                FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                ***StorageReference mStorageRef = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://bucketname.appspot.com"); //line 163***
                                final StorageReference photoRef = mStorageRef.child("posts_images/mooseImg" + getCurrentDateTime() + ".jpg");
                                UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.putBytes(data);
                                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                    }
                                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                        Firebase createNewPost = new Firebase(FirebaseURL);
                                        Firebase alanRef = createNewPost.push();
                                        Map<String, Object> nickname = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                        nickname.put("createdAt", getCurrentDateTime());
                                        nickname.put("imageURL", downloadUrl.toString());
                                    /*nickname.put("latitude", 20.1814);
                                    nickname.put("longitude", 72.1781);*/
                                        nickname.put("latitude", prefs.getLatitude());
                                        nickname.put("longitude", prefs.getLongitude());
                                        nickname.put("objectId", alanRef.getKey());
                                        nickname.put("ownerId", prefs.getUserUId());
                                        nickname.put("postText", editTextNewPostMsg.getText().toString());
                                        nickname.put("replies", 0);
                                        nickname.put("reportCount", 0);
                                        nickname.put("score", 0);
                                        nickname.put("updatedAt", getCurrentDateTime());
                                        alanRef.setValue(nickname, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                                                dismissProgressDialog();
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your post have been added.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });
```

//                                    LogUtil.debug("StorageRef = " + mStorageRef);
                                        }
                                    });

Comment: Please inline code and put more details about the error and expected behavior (line, stacktrace).

Comment: There's nothing in the code related to the error message you are seeing, with the exception of the "supplied bucketname" on line 163 being "not available to this project".  Perhaps you have the bucketname wrong?  Perhaps something not configured right for access in Firebase?  We don't know.

Comment: I use the bucket from console available for my project. Rules are ok . last library. I really don t know why I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in your google-services.json file with tag "storage_bucket"

"project_info": {
    "project_number": "816275527980",
    "firebase_url": "https://project-8693710910123456789.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "project-8693710910123456789",
    "storage_bucket": "project-8693710910123456789.appspot.com"
  },